# Find all conformal automorphisms

Tags: complex-analysis

Let G be a non-empty simply connected and bounded domain in $\mathbb{C}$ and let $a, b \in G $ with $a \neq b$. Find all conformal automorphisms of G such that a dn b are two fixed points. Moreover, let $\Omega = G \setminus \{a,b\}$. Find all conformal automorphisms of $\Omega$.

I am totally lost for this question. The only clue I have is that Riemann mapping theorem should be useful, but I don't know how to continue.
Appreciate any help. Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Yes, the Riemann mapping theorem is useful.  Essentially it lets you assume $G$ is a disk.  Can you solve the problem for a disk?

Comment: Yup. I have just proved that if G is a unit disk and f is a conformal automorphism from G to G with two distinct fixed points a and b, then f(z) = z. But what then?

Comment: If $\phi$ is a conformal automorphism from $G$ to the disk, and $f$ is one from $G$ to $G$, then $\phi \circ f \circ \phi^{-1}$ is ...

Comment: Oh...I see. I have been working on decomposing $\phi$ into $G \rightarrow \mathbb{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{D} \rightarrow G$. Wrong direction. Thank you very much.